# Download a video using ytdl-core and let client download it at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, ytdl

I made a YouTube video downloader using ytdl-core and the way it works is:.
Downloads the file in the server and thrn send a link to the client.

I wonder if it would be possible to let ytdl-core download the video and while the video is getting downloaded let the client download it too before ytdl finishes the download.

Comment: You might need to take a look at streaming files to client. but before doing it, maybe do some tests to see how long it takes to  retrieve videos from youtube because streaming files to users has it downfalls. like user starting to download the file but if server fails to complete it's own download then user wont be able to retrieve the file either. also if you are implementing the stream, it's better to show end user file size because browser probably wont be able to determine it.

Comment: @PooyaEstakhri Do you have any idea on how to show the user end file size?

Comment: No i havent used it but maybe you get the info while retrieving download options or be able to have an estimate based on bitrate and duration of video.